# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet while trying to use Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to study Spring following this guide http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html
I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat. I tried to add Spring jars both in the lib folder and java build path (function of eclipse).
I tried to add the  spring.jar,   spring-webmvc.jar and commons-logging.jar following the guide. I even tried to add all the jar from Spring framework 3.1, 3.2 and 4.1. But i get always the same error when i start Tomcat

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

this is my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app version="2.4"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" >

      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
          index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Post full stack trace of error log.

Comment: Yeah, a stack trace would help people help you.

Comment: Please make sure that tomcat have the run time dependency of the `org.springframework.web.servlet.jar` jar.Or this issue might also due to the incompitable jar or conflicting jars

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, Please check your Spring-web Release version, Use Spring-Web-3.0.6 release, and spring-webmvc 3.0.0 release jar, I hope it will solve the problem.

Comment: Im using the 3.1.4
Do u think the problem is the version?

Comment: It may be, will you find "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet" class in your build path?

Comment: and don't use same jar with different version, Its also leads to the exception, use only one version of each type.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `org.springframework.web.servlet.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: Is it in your war in the directory WEB-INF/lib ?

Answer (score 0):

please make sure springapp-servlet.xml
file is present in the 
/WEB-INF/springapp-servlet.xml

And also check if all the dependencies 
of spring-web jars in the lib/buildpath.